# Deepspeech realtime speech to text

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio, mozilla-deepspeech

How can I do real-time speech to text using deep speech and a microphone?

I tried running this script I found on GitHub, but when I run it and I do not say anything for a while, it starts printing random text.

```
import pyaudio
import deepspeech
import numpy as np
from queue import SimpleQueue

BUFFERS_PER_SECOND = 10
SAMPLE_WIDTH = 2
BEAM_WIDTH = 512

#switch between tensorflow and tensorflow light model
#MODEL_PATH = 'deepspeech-0.8.1-models.tflite'
MODEL_PATH = 'models\DeepSpeech\deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm'

SCORER_PATH = 'models\DeepSpeech\deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer'

buffer_queue = SimpleQueue()


def audio_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
    buffer_queue.put(np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype='int16'))
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)


def find_device(pyaudio, device_name):
    ''' find specific device or return default input device'''
    default = pyaudio.get_default_input_device_info()
    for i in range(pyaudio.get_device_count()):
        name = pyaudio.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name']
        if name == device_name:
            return (i, name)
    return (default['index'], default['name'])


def main():
    model = deepspeech.Model(MODEL_PATH)
    model.setBeamWidth(BEAM_WIDTH)
    model.enableExternalScorer(SCORER_PATH)

    stream = model.createStream()

    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    index, name = find_device(audio, 'pulse')

    print(f'select device {name}')

    buffer_size = model.sampleRate() // BUFFERS_PER_SECOND
    audio_stream = audio.open(rate=model.sampleRate(),
                              channels=1,
                              format=audio.get_format_from_width(
                                  SAMPLE_WIDTH, unsigned=False),
                              input_device_index=index,
                              input=True,
                              frames_per_buffer=buffer_size,
                              stream_callback=audio_callback)

    num_iterations = BUFFERS_PER_SECOND * 2
    i = 0
    while audio_stream.is_active():
        stream.feedAudioContent(buffer_queue.get())
        if i % num_iterations == 0:
            text = stream.intermediateDecode()
            if text.find('stop') >= 0:
                break
            print(text)
        i += 1

    print(stream.finishStream())
    audio_stream.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    #find_device()
```

I know there are other options, but every option I found was either free trial or instantly paying. So if someone could help me work with DeepSpeech, or if somebody knows a free alternative, I would really appreciate it

Comment: when you say "found", where? what have you tried so far? do you understand what the script does? perhaps PyAudio provides some threshold argument or method? do you have some way to check the live input from your mic? does it show some rogue or quiet input?